# Why is my Vue v-if conditional render very slow (sometimes) when within v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-for

I am using Vuetify and have a v-for loop to display a list of items.

I want an 'expand' button for each button that expands the displayed list item to include extra content. I don't want to expand all the items, just the one that is clicked.

While my code works. It is only fast on the first iteration. After that it gets very slow, but then sometimes renders quickly. Is it a problem with my code?

I am currently adding an 'expanded' prop to my list item object. Is there a different way to conditionally render individual items in a list?

Code below.

```
<template>
  <v-list>
    <div v-for="group in groups" :key="group">
      <h4 class="ml-4 my-2">{{ group }}</h4>

      <template v-for="item in actors">
        <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
          <v-card :elevation="hover ? 6 : 2" class="mx-4 my-2">
            <v-list-item
              :key="item.id"
              v-if="item.relation === group.toLowerCase()"
            >
              <v-list-item-icon class="mr-3">
                <v-btn
                  small
                  icon
                  color="secondary"
                  @click="expandListItem(item)"
                >
                  <v-icon>
                    {{
                      listItemExpanded ? "mdi-chevron-up" : "mdi-chevron-down"
                    }}
                  </v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <!-- style="cursor: pointer" @click="open(item)" -->
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.name }}</v-list-item-title>
                <div v-if="item.expanded">
                  Show this content
                </div>
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <UiDotMenu
                  :actions="listItemActions"
                  :payload="item"
                  @removeActor="removeActor"
                />
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-card>
        </v-hover>
      </template>
    </div>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

Method

```
    expandListItem(item) {
      item.expanded ? (item.expanded = false) : (item.expanded = true);
    },
```

Comment: Instead of creating a seperate function in a loop, can't you do like this- `<v-btn @click="item.expanded = !item.expanded"><v-icon> {{ item.expanded ? "mdi-chevron-up" : "mdi-chevron-down"}}</v-icon></v-btn>`

Comment: Try to add a `:key` attribute in the `<v-hover>` component under your second `v-for`. This will help vue to avoid re-rendering elements when the state changes.

Comment: Starting from Vue v3.2 you can also apply [`v-memo`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo) to speed up.

Comment: @NehaSoni My initial objects didn't include the item.expanded prop so couldn't do that. However, I'm now adding that prop when fetching from the API in order to implement your suggestion. Simpler code so have used your suggestion. Doesn't help with speed unfortunately.

Comment: @Kapcash I've tried adding the key but still slow. If I remove the v-hover completely it's still slow. I think perhaps it's just my dev environment/browser. First click is often fast, but successive clicks get slower.

Comment: @Ash Try to debug your template rendering by: 1. migrating your `<v-card>` template part to a component, 2. add a `console.log()` in the `updated` lifecycle method of this component. If all the components log when you expand an item, that mean they all re-render, and they should not. How did you added the `:key` prop to the `v-hover`?

Comment: @Kapcash Thanks, I tried and it wasn't re-rendering all the components. It didn't have anything to do with the v-hover as the problem was present even without it. It seemed to have to do with the nested v-for loops inside the v-list. I've revamped to use vuetify's built-in v-list-group which works flawlessly. I'll update my post.

Comment: I never mentioned it was `v-hover`'s fault, but rather an over-rendering issue. You have to be sure Vue can reuse the components when re-rendering to avoid executing the nested loop at every render.

Comment: @Kapcash Thanks, I misunderstood. I'm new to coding so sometimes it's hard to understand what people are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what was causing the problem but I implemented a much better solution by using vuetify's v-list-group which does much the same thing and works instantly.

Here is the revised code in case its useful for someone.

```
<v-list>
  <div v-for="(group, index) in groupedActors" :key="index">
    <h4 class="ml-4 my-2 toCapitalFirst">{{ index }}</h4>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-group v-model="actor.expanded" v-for="actor in group">
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="actor.name"></v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle
              v-text="actor.nationality.name"
            ></v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <UiDotMenu
              :actions="listItemActions"
              :payload="actor"
              @removeActor="removeActor"
            />
          </v-list-item-action>
        </template>

        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <ActorAddressCard :actor="actor" />
                <ActorClassifierCard
                  :actor="actor"
                  group="Registration Numbers"
                />
                <ActorClassifierCard :actor="actor" group="Other" />
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" md="6">
                <ActorClassifierCard :actor="actor" group="Email" />

                <ActorClassifierCard :actor="actor" group="Phone" />
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </div>
</v-list>
```